# How can I abstract away the .swf named from an embeddable Flash tag?

Tags: flash, embed, uri

Youtubes flash player has embed links like http://www.youtube.com/v/5oiQdTfMAmo&hl=en&fs=1&

How can I do the same thing, where there is no mention of .swf and the file that the player points to is encoded in the URI.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done via rewrite rules on the server. I'm not sure how it works with other web servers, but with Apache you use mod_rewrite and some special regex in your .htaccess file.